# Why can't I access the element of a vector in an array with array[i].x?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I get this Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

```
let array = [];
let vector = new THREE.Vector3(2,3,2);
array.push(vector);
console.log(array[-1].x);
```

Comment: `array[-1]` returns the last array element in Python, but not in JavaScript

Comment: ok thank you, I googled it and there it said -1 works too

Comment: @BurakErtan Do you have a link to that wrong statement?

Comment: @BurakErtan Where did you read that? That's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to access the last element of array, try

```
array[array.length - 1]
```

or even better, try ES-2022 [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

```
array.at(-1)
```